# Trouble getting Javascript custom event fired onkeyup, onchange etc

Tags: javascript

I made a reusable table view which takes a table definition (JSON array) and data (JSON) and renders the table using javascript. I made the table using an mvc pattern like [here](https://alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript) updated for es6.

I have hard coded events in the view which work great within instances of my model, view and controller. These events are things like "addRowClicked" and "modelChanged" which then calls a callback function to operate.

For example On the view I created the event:

```
this.addRowClicked = new CIEvent(this);
```

On the Controller I attach the callback:

```
this.view.addRowClicked.attach(
        function() {
            self.addRow()
        }
    );
```

Then when creating the view I can pass a button array with an event name which creates the button and attaches the notify method of the event when clicked

```
element.onclick = function () {
            self[button.event_name].notify();
        }
```

So that all works perfect and is pretty awesome!!

Now I am trying to add custom events without luck. A Custom event would be something like "updateQuantity" which is unique to an instance of the table. updateQuantity would get fired from an input element when changing  and would sum up specified cells and put that sum in a different cell.

I thought I would be able to simply create the event on the view, attach the callback on the controller, then attach the event notification to onchange or onkeyup... etc

But that is not working.

Here is some extracted code of the entire process....

To build the table I do this:

```
 let model = new TableModel(table_definition, data);
 let view = new DataTableView(model, div, buttons);
 let controller = new DataTableController(model, view);
```

Now I add the event 'updateQuantity' on the view and the callback on the controller:

```
view.updateQuantity = new CIEvent(view);
controller.view.updateQuantity.attach(
        function() {
            console.log('update the quantity row')
        }
    );
```

If I then call the event from the within same file it works fine:

```
view.updateQuantity.notify(); // works fine
```

However, if I try to attach this to an an element onclick, onkeyup, etc, the event will not fire... the commented code attaches dynamically however I just hardwired it to try to get it working. I tried using events like onkeyup directly and using addEventListener

```
        let self = this;
        // element[index] =  this[event[index]].notify(); 
        // element.onkeyup =  this.updateQuantity.notify();
        element.addEventListener("onkeyup", function(){
            // self[event[index]].notify();
            self.updateQuantity.notify();
         });
```

When modifying the element I get no response.

I hope I am missing something elementary. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
element.addEventListener("onkeyup", function(){
        // self[event[index]].notify();
        self.updateQuantity.notify();
     });
```

Should be

```
element.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
            // self[event[index]].notify();
            self.updateQuantity.notify();
         });
```

onkeyup should have been keyup